# Lemonstand: Skip shipping method in checkout

Tags: php, e-commerce

A client will always have free shipping for all of their products sold through their [Lemonstand](http://www.lemonstand.com) store, so they want the Shipping Method step removed from the checkout, as it would be an unnecessary extra click for the user. And since it's a free shipping on every item regardless, they didn't want to have to set a unique 'free shipping' option on every product in the store, which would also be laborious.

Initially I simply removed and `unset()` the `shipping_method` value from my **checkout;progress.php** partial, like so:

```
<?php 
$steps = array(
    'billing_info'      => 'Billing info',
    'shipping_info'     => 'Shipping info',
    //'shipping_method' => 'Shipping method',
    'payment_method'    => 'Payment method',
    'review'            => 'Order review'
);

unset($steps['shipping_method']);

?>
```

*(The unset is in place because Lemonstand has a tendency to overwrite these values based on the product types in the checkout process)*

However, this results in an error during checkout: **"Please select a shipping method"** - which makes sense, as we're not setting it to anything. Any ideas on how to skip this step *and* set a default shipping method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this can be achieved with a single line of PHP, which I added to the **checkout;payment_method.php** partial, including the above steps to remove the Shipping Method step from the checkout.

First off, I created a table rate shipping option, with the Country, State, & City all set to * (wildcard), and a cost of **0**. Then I gave it an API code of `default`.

In the **checkout;payment_method.php** partial, I added the following line:

```
Shop_CheckoutData::set_shipping_method(Shop_ShippingOption::find_by_api_code('default')->id);
```

This way, the Shipping Method step is removed from the customer-facing checkout process, but shipping is still automatically selected and calculated during checkout.